# Radix 2 DIT Twiddle factor calculation VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fft

So, I've been trying to implement an N length FFT in VHDL but I can't seem to get the right outputs. I believe it's because of the Twiddle Factor but I'm unsure, I've been troubleshooting this for a while but can't find the solution

I've tried changing the Twiddle factor to another formula described on a couple of websites `((k/2**Stage)/N)`, like this, from one twiddle factor calculation website but it does not work.

```
constant M : integer := 3;

constant N : integer := 8;

constant Nminus1 : integer := 7;

constant TwoPiN : real := 2.0*MATH_PI/real(N);

Butterfly code : 

 TempRe := xtmp(kNs).re *WCos - xtmp(kNs).re * WSin;

 TempIm := xtmp(kNs).im*WCos + xtmp(kNs).im*Wsin;

 xtmp(kNs).re := xtmp(k).re - TempRe;

 xtmp(kNs).im := xtmp(k).im - TempIm;

 xtmp(k).re := xtmp(k).re + TempRe;

 xtmp(k).im := xtmp(k).im + TempIm;


 Main:process(x_in)

 variable Ns, count ,Stage, k, kNs, p ,p_int, M1: integer;

 variable Wcos, Wsin : real;

 variable x : complexArr;


 begin

 x := x_in; --copy insignal

 Ns := N; 

 M1 := M;

 count := 0;


 for Stage in 1 to M loop

 k := 0;

 Ns := Ns/2; --index distance between a dual node pair

 M1 := M1 - 1;


  while(k< N) loop


 for n in 1 to Ns loop

 p := Digit_Reverse(k/2**(M-1));


 Wcos := cos(TwoPiN*real(p));--W to the power of p


 Wsin := - sin(TwoPiN*real(p)); --W = exp(\u2212 j2\u03c0/N)


 kNs := k + Ns;

 Butterfly(x,k,kNs,Wcos,Wsin);

 k := k + 1;

 count := count +1;

 end loop;

 k := k + Ns;

 end loop;

 end loop;

 Unscramble(x); --output

 x_ut <= x;
```

No errors but I expect the correct values, for 2048 length FFT, but at the moment I'm troubleshooting the 16 point FFT and 8 point FFT with [-1;i]-[1;i] etc.

Comment: What does your testbench say?

Comment: a = [-1+i;-1+i;1+i;1+i;1+i;1+i;1+1i;1+1i] I'm feeding this for 8 points, and matlab says i should get [4 + 8i;-3.414 + 1.414i;-2.000 + 2.000i;-0.585+ 1.414i;0+0i;
-0.58 - 1.414i;-2 - 2i;-3.41 - 1.414i]. And I get [4+8i;0+0i;-4+0i;0+0i;0+0i;-4+0i;0+0i;-4+0i]. So some are correct but most are false.